# File as a executable jar file - sound / pictures don't work with gui button(s)

Tags: java, image, user-interface, audio, wav

Yes I have researched online stackflow I believe was one place.  And they have questions that "sound / audio" and i believe also "pictures" dont play from executable jar file.

The wav files are in the jar file...i used winrar to check.

I ran from the command prompt,  and the sound wouldnt play. And one of the errors that was given was that :

java.io.FileNotFoundException : C:\Users\Bijan\Desktop\Sounds\SexySounds1.wav (The system can not find the path specified)

etc...I have another thing to add.  That the pictures actually do work on the button when only pictures are used from executable jar file,  but audio doesn't seem to play when I try to use a button that implements audio (wav) files.

This code below sets opt for JOptionPane,  and I just put the images inside that box,  and the audio (wav) files. This below code is for the button "Relax" for the gui program.

```
JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Relax");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private int counter = 0;
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                  String soundName1 = "Sounds/SexySounds1.wav";
                  String soundName1a = "Sounds/SexySounds2a.wav";
                  String soundName2 = "Sounds/HoShit.wav";
                  String soundName3 = "Sounds/SexySounds2.wav";
                  AudioInputStream audioInputStream = null;

                  JOptionPane opt = new JOptionPane(""); 
                  opt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(210, 325));
                  final JDialog dialogBoxTitle = opt.createDialog("Sexy Woman");
                  try{
                  if(counter == 0){


                      Image pic = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/SexyWoman.png")).getImage();
                      opt.setIcon(new ImageIcon(pic));
                      audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(soundName1).getAbsoluteFile());


                  }
                  if(counter == 1){
                      Image pic = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/Sexy Woman #2.jpeg")).getImage();
                        opt.setIcon(new ImageIcon(pic));
                        audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(soundName2).getAbsoluteFile());
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500L);


                        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {

                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                      }
                  if(counter == 2){
                      Image pic = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/SexyWoman#3.jpeg")).getImage();
                        opt.setIcon(new ImageIcon(pic));
                        audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(soundName1a).getAbsoluteFile());

                      }
                  if(counter == 3){
                      Image pic = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/SexyWoman#4.jpeg")).getImage();
                        opt.setIcon(new ImageIcon(pic));
                        audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(soundName3).getAbsoluteFile());

                      }
                  if(counter == 4){
                      Image pic = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/Bijan's Picture.png")).getImage();
                        opt.setIcon(new ImageIcon(pic));
                      }} catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) {

                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e1) {

                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Clip clip = null;
                        try {
                            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                        } catch (LineUnavailableException e1) {

                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            clip.open(audioInputStream);
                        } catch (LineUnavailableException e1) {

                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e1) {

                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        clip.start();
                        counter++;
                  new Thread(new Runnable()
                        {
                          public void run()
                          {
                            try{


                              Thread.sleep(1500);

                              }catch (InterruptedException e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }}}).start();
                                dialogBoxTitle.setVisible(true);

            }

            }
        );
```

Bijan

PS : I wanted to truly see if the wav files were in the jar file,  and when I run the command prompt :
java -jar "SuperMathBattler1a.jar"  the program runs.  Yet when I try to view contents of the jar file  using :

jar tf SuperMathBattler1a.jar

Then it gives this error :

'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I researched and what was written was that I have to alter the "PATH"  yet that doesnt make sense since when I run it it works,  so the path should be correct right?  There maybe is something really fu--ed with this computer.  I run from command prompt with :

C:\Users\Bijan\Desktop>

and I enter jar tf filename.jar

jar file is in desktop folder,  yet doesnt view contents of jar file,  yet runs it when I input --- java -jar "filename.jar"

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner in java myself. Made a GUI an executable .jar. I had the same problem you have. My GUI has different pics for different listeners and a .wav for one. My executable .jar wouldn't show or play them. What no one told me, and I found out by just making an assumption. The jar is only "saving" the paths to those files, but the files themselves must still be included into the same folder as the jar file. If ever they are separated the jar will execute without them.

Example:
I made the original .jar in the original class folder I ran everything from in JCreator. The .jar runs as intended because all the pics and the .wav were in that folder.

I copy and pasted the .jar to a new folder exclusively for itself on my desktop. Clicked it to run, and it ran without the pics or the wav.

I copy and pasted the pics and .wav to that same .jar exclusive folder and it ran exactly as I intended pics, music, and all.

One cool thing I learned from that as a beginner in java is that I can create a generically titled file path, but use different pics in different .jar folders to make the .jar customable.
Example:
To the same aforementioned .jar I added a listener to set a friends face pic on the gui after log in.

The path in the code has
friendsPic =new imageIcon("friend.jpg").

In my listener for "Log In" I added If(logIn.equals("Sarah")||logIn.equals("Deena")) then add friendsPic to panel.

The difference is, I made a .jar with this code. I duplicated the .jar into two seperate folders. One I want to send to my friend Deena, the other for Sarah. Deena's folder has the .jar and  a .jpg of her title "friend". Sarah's folder has the exact same .jar as well as a .jpg of her titled "friend". The .jar doesn't know the difference between the pics just that it has a path to a file labeled friend. I can run both .jars from there respective folders. Because Deena's folder has Deena's pic labeled friend, her jar displays her pic. Because Sarah's folder has her pic labeled friend, her jar displays her pic.

I hope this helps even if it wasnt the precise answer a more experienced programmer could have given.

Comment: The thing first thank you for ur attempt to help me. But I'm confused. Because after I get the jar file to work ok, I will then convert it to a regular .exe file so it can opened just with a double click.  The way u r explaining I'm not sure but I would have to create another jar file and it would work only as an executable jar file inside a newly created folder, yet what if I convert that to an .exe fIle will it still work I'm not sure. So can u please explain to me what I should do I'm confused, so I add another folder and my path...could u please break it down more...

Comment: So I can make a jar file inside another folder u wrote that the file will execute if separated, so basically ur logic is that the files are being separated therefore the sound is not playing. But the pictures do work though. It's just the audio won't work. It has something to do with the gui button press. When I have preset pics that are not implemented with button press, pics show. When I use pics themselves with button press, pics work. When I use audio with button press, then audio doesn't seem to play. I guess u mean the path as in Sounds/SexySounds1.wav right ?

Comment: The project folder is set up like this :  AwesomeGuiRpg1a (project name) > AwesomeGuiRpg1aCharacterPics (source folder) > AwesomeGuiProject1aPackage (package) > and within the package there are 11 files.java...within the project folder AwesomeGuiRpg1a I also have 4 source folders --- pic, Sounds, Sounds2, dataSaveLoad...so I notice when I create the jar file,  it shows which files are being put into the jar,  and it shows wav files being put in.  So I am assuming the wav files are all in the jar file.  What do mean by path?  Do you mean i